# How do I add sensitivity to Quaternion? C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, quaternions

I have this script with a sensitivity variable but cannot figure out where do I add it in the code. Any experts able to help me out here?

I want to add this:

```
public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
```

into this code for the Quaternion rotation:

```
switch (firstTouch.phase)
{
    case TouchPhase.Began:
        firstpoint = firstTouch.position;
        xAngTemp = xAngle;
        yAngTemp = yAngle;
        break;

    case TouchPhase.Moved:
        secondpoint = firstTouch.position;
        //Mainly, about rotate camera. For example, for Screen.width rotate on 180 degree
        xAngle = xAngTemp  + (secondpoint.x - firstpoint.x) * 180.0f / Screen.width;
        yAngle = yAngTemp  - (secondpoint.y - firstpoint.y) * 90.0f / Screen.height;
        //Rotate camera
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0.0f);
        character.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0.0f);
        break;
}
```

Comment: What does sensitivity mean? What is your purpose effect? Does you want to lerp rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an expert but what about simply multiplying it like

```
xAngle = xAngTemp  + (secondpoint.x - firstpoint.x) * 180f  * sensitivity / Screen.width;
yAngle = yAngTemp  - (secondpoint.y - firstpoint.y) * 90f * sensitiviy / Screen.height;
```

Though I would recommend to rather use a `Vector2` in order to be able to use individual sensitivties for x and y

```
public Vector2 sensitivtiy = Vector2.one * 5f;

...

xAngle = xAngTemp  + (secondpoint.x - firstpoint.x) * 180f  * sensitivity.x / Screen.width;
yAngle = yAngTemp  - (secondpoint.y - firstpoint.y) * 90f * sensitiviy.y / Screen.height;
```